# Make an image link to facebook or another website inside of Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to do an image which links the user to a new website for example facebook.com. So far here is what I got.

```
$imghtml=CHtml::image('images/imageSlider/397498913','Test');
echo CHtml::link($imghtml, $this->createAbsoluteUrl('https://www.facebook.com/'));
```

This does display an image on the website but the link is wrong, when i click on this i go to the following link. `http://localhost:63342/France2014/index.php?r=https://www.facebook.com`.

How do i make it link to just facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `echo CHtml::link($imghtml, 'https://www.facebook.com/');`

The method `createUrl()` always creates an internal Yii link inside your application.

Comment: Hello sorry for the late replay, Yes thank you that fixed it for me, Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try following -

```html
$imghtml=CHtml::image('images/imageSlider/397498913','Test');

echo CHtml::link($imghtml, CHtml::normalizeUrl('https://www.facebook.com/'));
```

Hope it will help you.